# if cell A1 contains certain text , formula cell C1 value = value already in cell B1

Tags: formula

I need a formula for cell C1 that accomplishes the following:

If cell A1 contains certain text "KW", regardless of other text or numbers, formula cell C1 value = value already in cell B1

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("KW",A1)),B1,"?")